# Acortar url en hosting y dominio real(GODADDY)

Tags: apache, url, hosting, godaddy

Saludos soy nuevo en esto de los dominios y hosting y no he podido encontrar una solucion a mi problema, cuando en mi pagina web le doy clic al boton ingresar para que me envie a la pantalla de inicio de sesion en vez de salir:

www.voypalla.net/login, sale esto:

www.voypalla.ent/Home/Login/login.php

que seria carpeta/subcarpeta/archivo.extension

yo quisiera primero que no salga la extension .php o .html o la que sea y segundo que salga directamente porque es un riesgo que todos conozcan las carpetas en las que se alojan los archivos de mi website. segun tengo entendido la configuracion se hace en el archivo .htaccess con expresiones regulares pero no se como, les dejo por aqui la configuracion que tiene el mio:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?voypalla.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/voypalla/Home
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /voypalla/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?voypalla.net$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ voypalla/Home/index.html [L]

Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A432000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A432000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A432000
ExpiresByType image/png A432000
ExpiresByType image/ico A432000
ExpiresByType image/bmp A432000
ExpiresByType text/css A432000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A432000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A432000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A432000
</ifmodule>

<Files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|dist|fla|inc|ini|log|psd|sh|sql|swp)|~)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Eso tiene que ver más con la forma de trabajar que tienes que con las configuraciones que hay en el .htaccess, ¿estás usando algún framework de PHP o es PHP puro y crudo?

Comment: es php crudito.

Comment: Para que se despliegue como www.voypalla.net/login según tengo entendido debería ser a través de un web service, es la forma en la que conozco que se puede hacer así